# Fatal Error when enabling In-Place Editor in Panel

Tags: panels

When enabling the in-place-editor in a panel and then visiting the page with the panel I get the following error: Fatal error: Class 'panels_renderer_editor' not found

In the log file there is entry saying:
Plugin editor des Plugin Tpys panels: display_renderers refers to a nonexistent file:
sites/all/modules/panels/plugins/display_renderers/mlpanels_panels_renderer_editor.class.php

and that's true!
The mlpanels module with this file is outside of panels module in a separate directory.

What is wrong?

Comment: It's obviously a modified/hacked version of Panels since I just downloaded [panels from Drupal.org](https://drupal.org/project/panels) both version 6.x and 7.x and there's no mlpanels_panels_rendered_editor.class.php in any of those versions.

Comment: same what I have done. I downloaded it (again) this morning (Panels 7.x-3.3) deleted all already installed modules (panels, panels image link, multilingual panels) and reinstalled all of them again. Everything plain vanilla, no changes of any sort in these modules.

Comment: Then it looks like a bug in the module.